# Google Apps Script - how to applies this code for multiple sheets in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

this code applies for just  one sheet in a google sheet, how can i use to get four character in other sheets too.

```
function truncate() {
    const R        = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SheetId");
    const Choices  = R.getSheetByName("Choices");
    const Hrange = Choices.getRange("H2:H");
    const data    = Hrange.getValues().flat().map(r => [r.toString().substring(0,4)] );
    Hrange.setValues(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets) or [getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename) to get all sheets or selected sheets respectively. Either way, you need to iterate over all the selected sheets and one way to do that is to use [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

### Solution for all sheets:

```
function truncate() {
  const R = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SheetId");
  const sheets = R.getSheets(); // for all sheets
  sheets.forEach(sh=>{
    var Hrange = sh.getRange("H2:H");
    var data = Hrange.getValues().flat().map(r => [r.toString().substring(0,4)] );
    Hrange.setValues(data);
    });
}
```

### Solution for selected sheets by name:

```
function truncate() {
  const R = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SheetId");
  const sheets = ['Choices','Copy of Choices'].map(ch=>R.getSheetByName(ch)); // for selected sheets based on name
  sheets.forEach(sh=>{
    var Hrange = sh.getRange("H2:H");
    var data = Hrange.getValues().flat().map(r => [r.toString().substring(0,4)] );
    Hrange.setValues(data);
    });
}
```

In this solution please modify `['Choices','Copy of Choices']` to use the sheet names of your choice.